# Increment inside for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, increment

I do not understand why the last i = 5, where is the final increment of variable i?

```
var i;
for( i = 0; i <5; ){
  console.log("i = " + i);  // i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
  i = i + 1;
}
console.log(i); // i = 5
```

Comment: Value of `i` is incremented but it fails in the `i < 5` condition hence `for-loop` is terminated.

Comment: `for( i = 0; i <=5; ){` would have given you the "last" increment, but it's like the basic of the basics of for-loop

Answer (score 1):

The for loop only stops if the condition is not met. In this case, i = 5 after it is increased inside the last loop. Hence, it breaks out of the condition. Therefore i is 5 when it is printed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what exactly do you asked for. 
If you want to loop greater than equal to 5. You should use `i <= 5` it will displays `0 1 2 3 4 5`.

You get the output `0 1 2 3 4` because of this condition `i < 5`.

It would be better if you study basic of loopings: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp